# Rally: Maximum number of test results for each test case

Tags: rally, testcase

Is there a limit to the number of testcase results we can assign to a testcase in Rally. I want to run regression test and add testcase results everyday. Would it be ok?

Thanks,
Haris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have thousands of Testcases and assuming it really is only once a day instead of every build, then you should have no trouble. Rally continues to perform well with many artifacts as recently confirmed by a [performance study](http://www.rallydev.com/resource/alm-performance-study).

Disclosure: I am Director of Analytics for Rally Software.

Answer (score 1):

As such there is no upper limit.